# Non-interactive SSH GPG Agent forwarding with pre-existing connection

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, expect, gnupg

I have got a bit of a chicken/ egg problem here.

**The Problem**

I would like to SSH to a remote machine and forward my local gpg-agent. The problem is that the gpg-agent on the remote machine only starts once the SSH connection is established. While the gpg-agent is NOT running on the remote machine, I cannot connect to the remote machine via SSH while specifying the forwarding.

In the light of this, this command does not work, since the remote gpg-agent is not running and therefore the **/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent** does not exist yet.

```
ssh -R /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent user@remotemachine
```

**The Workaround**

The alternative is to do it **interactively/ manually** as shown below.

```
ssh user@remotemachine
```

I am now connected via SSH and as a side effect, the gpg-agent got automatically started too.

When I now update the existing SSH connection, by opening the SSH PTY:

```
[enter]
~C
ssh> -R /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
Forwarding port.
[enter]
```

I can now run my GPG commands on the remote machine by the use of my local gpg-agent.

**The Aim**

I would like to have the above workaround automated. Basically I want to SSH to the remote machine with `ssh user@remotemachine` and the remote machine will then automatically add the SSH forwarding to the existing SSH connection.

**The Question**

How can I make the remote machine **automatically** update the newly established SSH connection and add the gpg-agent forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used the `expect` tag, here is a simple `expect` script that should suffice.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@remotemachine
expect {$ }
send "date\r"
expect {$ }
send "~C"
expect "ssh> "
send -- "-R /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent\r"
expect -timeout 5  timeout exit   "\r\n"
send "echo ok\r"
expect "\nok\r"
expect {$ }
interact
```

Put this in a file and do `chmod +x` on it. For some reason, I found I didn't get the `Forwarding port` message from the `-R` command unless I enabled `ssh -v`, so I just check for `\r\n`, but you can change this. Also, I assumed the shell prompt from the remote was `$`, so you might need to change that too, but if your prompt is `[enter]` then you need to say

```
expect -ex {[enter]}
```

to avoid the string being interpreted as a regular expression.

Comment: **This is absolutely brilliant and works like a charm!** Before posting this question I had been trying with `expect` but tried to run it after the SSH connection was established. Even if I would have had it got working, yours would still be better as it's more secure since the `expect` code is initiated right when establishing the SSH connection from the client.